# Creating/editing a php dynamic page

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, phpmyadmin, craigslist

Ok i have a dynamic page where people can post events in the city, we will call that page: city.php. In order to get to the page though, you must select a state from states.php, then a city from allcities.php. The states and cities are all in mysql database. On the city.php page you can click "add event" and it will take you to createevent.php where you can create and add an event that shows on city.php. But here is what i want to do:

I want to make it so that city.php is the central spot for posting different things for that city. I want a page for events, news, jobs, and for sale. On the city.php you will select a link for those pages taking you to pages such as events.php, news.php, jobs.php, and sale.php. How can i keep all those pages dynamic and related to the selected city? I toyed around and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: that's quite a bit of page loading. consider switching to use an ajax-based system that dynamically loads the cities based on the state selection, then save the selected city in a session variable, so it's available to all further pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do something like this in PHP. I personally disagree with your method as it sounds. I could be wrong about what it seems like you're saying though.

As adam said, $_SESSION is the first thing in mind. You can also look into $_COOKIE:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

or just pass the city id as a $_GET var:
http://www.yoursite.com/events.php?city=2

Then read it in PHP like

```
$city_id = $_GET['city'];
```

Comment: Passing around important sitewide variables in the URL is usually pretty kludgy, but in this case I think it's a good idea. It allows readers to easily switch to another city, makes your URLs easy to understand, and means that the URL will continue to go to the right place even if it's bookmarked or pasted into an email or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but do you want variables to cross over into other pages?  Take a look at PHP's use of sessions.  Sessions are very handy, it essentially allows you to have site-wide variables associated to each of your users.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Basically at the top of each of your pages just put:

```
session_start();
```

And then to assign / access a session variable you just call:

```
$_SESSION['city'] = $city;
```

or

```
echo $_SESSION['city'];
```

Comment: i think this may be what i am looking for, once a user clicks the page then i guess i could do a query to pull out all the info that has alread been entered in the database for that particular city

Comment: You can query the database each time or store it in a session variable.  I would recommend querying the database each time if its a large amount of information.  Session variables take up memory on the server, so you don't want to store TOO much there.  Session variables get set and carried over from page to page.

Comment: cant seem to do what i want in this comment, will make a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715547/how-to-correctly-use-sessions-for-dynamic-pages

Answer (score 0):

Quite generic but key is in the relational db structure. Displaying is easy, so make sure that news, job, events tables has `id_city` for building correct queries.

Example DB style as answer to your comment:

```
cities : id_city | city_name | city_slug | id_state
events : id_event | id_city | event_name | other_event_data | ...
jobs   : id_jobs | id_city | job_name | job_salary | etc.
```

So user clicks to `yoursite.com/washington`

Then you can query that comes from url (here is washington) like:

```
SELECT id_city FROM cities WHERE city_slug = "washington"
```

You got id_city now. Then if it is jobs,

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id_city = "above gotten id_city"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to draw attention that if he wants to store jobs, news, events based on city selection, it is not quite far to assume he is using a database for that. While creating event, news, etc, if he post and store the city id to database for relativity, then it is quite easier to fetch all news for example related to selected city by where city id equals to posted city id.

Comment: yes i am using a database, what is the best approach to create the other dynamic pages, session_start doesnt seem to be doing it. @yahya

Comment: @MikeYeah, check the revised answer. Good luck in your project.